# Использование Служб

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-service

Стоит задача сделать клиент к MS SQL базе, который общается со службой на сервере.
Сам служба отвечает на запросы пользователя и предоставляет необходимые данные с MS SQL сервера.
Помимо того, что служба отвечает на запросы клиента, служба должна выполнять в фоне некоторые действия с бд(Это не действия по запросу пользователя).

Подскажите, это можно сделать в рамках одной службы или нет?

Читал, что есть WCF службы, которые как раз подходят под первый пункт задания(Общение с клиентом), но не нашел информации могут ли они чего-нибудь еще в фоне делать.

Никогда ранее не работал со службами и буду признателен за ссылки на ресурсы и статьи.

Comment: WCF это веб-служба. Она состоит из методов, которые выполняются по запросу клиента. Выполнять в фоне можно, но оно в принципе не для этого задумано. Я бы посмотрел в сторону системных служб и self-hosted WCF.

Comment: self-hosted WCF- это когда, как я понимаю, на машине клиента сервис разворачивается, который выполняет всю необходимую логику? Не проще ли тогда вообще все реализовать в клиентском приложении? А в системную службу вы предлагаете спрятать логику фоновых операций?

Comment: _"могут ли они чего-нибудь еще в фоне делать."_ -- см. InstanceContextMode.Single - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx)

Comment: @iluxa1810, неправильно понимаете. [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая схема может выглядеть примерно так:
у вас 2 сущности - WCF-сервис принимающий запросы от клиентов (WCF) и Windows сервис обеспечивающий фоновые операции с БД (WS). Где разворачивать WCF по большому счету не имеет смысла, можете внутри веб-сервера IIS, можете внутри WS.

Архитектурно делать лучше не одной службой, а например так:

- отдельный проект WS. Занимается тем что запускается, после запуска активирует WCF и таймер. WCF начинает ждать запросов от клиента. По таймеру запускаются фоновые операции.
- отдельный проект WCF. Все стандартно.
- Отдельный проект с моделями БД, вспомогательными моделями DTO и операциями доступа к БД (репозиторием).

С такой компоновкой вы можете происпользовать модели в обоих сервисах совместно, сможете легко изменить БД (не меняя оба сервиса (WCF и WS)), можете увеличить количество сервисов....

если интересно, я реализовывал подобное. можете оценить проект на
https://github.com/zaebiz/MailBox

Comment: А можно про модели чуть подробнее? Если я не ошибаюсь, то модели используются в ORM и если я не собираюсь их использовать, то они мне не нужны? Я обычно всегда прямыми запросами обходился.

Comment: Я немного расширил понятие моделей... В посте описано, что в моделях может храниться класс-репозиторий, инкапсулирующий все ваши запросы к БД. Он может быть полезен и в WS и для WCF. Логично вынести его в отдельную либу. Я обычно укладываю в эту либу все вспомогательные общие сервисы - работа с БД, конфигами, кешем, логирование...

Кроме того, если вы не используете ORM, это не значит что у вас вообще нет моделей. Модели предметной области существуюи в любом проекте. Моделями могут быть объекты которыми вы обмениваетесь с клиентом.